# Select Number Into Multiple Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select on a table which selects a number

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

And I generates something that looks like

```
| column |
|   2    |
|   5    |
```

I am wondering if there is a way to turn that 2 and 5 into multiple rows of 2 and 5. So basically

```
| column |
|   2    |
|   2    |
|   5    |
|   5    |
|   5    |
|   5    |
|   5    |
```

Edit: As asked by a few what my ultimate goal is, is I am really trying to accomplish is a sort of ballot select, basically I store the number of ballots a person gets as a # and I want to turn that # into multiple rows so I can transfer it over to another program for the winner selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a numbers (aka tally) table:

```
SELECT col
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 AS num
  FROM (
     SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0  
            UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0  
            UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 ) AS x
  CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0  
            UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0  
            UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 ) AS y
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) AS var          
) AS t2 ON t1.col >= t2.num
ORDER BY col
```

The above query uses a numbers table with a range of values [1-100]. If your column contains bigger values then you have to grow the numbers table using additional `CROSS JOIN` operations.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50a51/1)

Comment: I would use `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` instead of multiple 0 just for clear reading. But do the same :)

Answer (score 0):

You can grow it exponentially with repeated joins to itself.

But what are you really trying to accomplish?

```
select
  a.*
from
  table a
  left join table b on 1=1
  left join table c on 1=1
```

Comment: What I am really trying to accomplish is a sort of ballot select, basically I store the number of ballots a person gets as a # and I want to turn that # into multiple rows so I can transfer it over to another program for the winner selection.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can add a table with two columns like:

```
|Id|Numbers|
|1 |   1   |
|2 |   2   |
|3 |   2   |
|4 |   3   |
|5 |   3   |
|6 |   3   |
|7 |   4   |
|. |  ...  |
|n |   n   |
```

Then you can use a

```
LEFT JOIN ON numbers = column
```

Otherwise you need to use a stored procedure with a loop depending on 'column' value

Comment: Do you have an example of the stored procedure?

Comment: @Steven Sorry, I haven't.