# Generate Series in Mysql, how to add a autoincrement at query?

Tags: mysql, series

I had a table with a column(c5) that contained a number x, I needed a SQL expression that repeated the same row x numbers of times:

My table A contained:

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
16  1   2   16  3
16  1   2   17  2 
16  1   2   18  1
```

And I needed:

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  n
16  1   2   16  3   1
16  1   2   16  3   2
16  1   2   16  3   3
16  1   2   17  2   1
16  1   2   17  2   2
16  1   2   18  1   1
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810984/select-number-into-multiple-rows/33811186#33811186

Answer (score 0):

I solved That with SQL expression:

```
SELECT
    c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, row_number AS n
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
        FROM
            tablea
        JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
        WHERE
            @curRow < (
                SELECT
                    max(c5)
                FROM
                    tablea
            )
    ) AS vwtable2
LEFT JOIN tablea d ON vwtable2.row_number <= tablea.c5;
```

Comment: `field1` is not included in the sample data provided in the OP. Is this an additional column?

Comment: Thanks for yur comment, I was updated the SQL query, field1 is a column c5 that had contain the number of times